# SQL Server - How SQL Server is choosing the best execution plan

Tags: sql, sql-server

As we know SQL Server chose the best plan based on statistics. I would like to know the rules which SQL Server uses when it is choosing the best plan. Please share a resource where the info is described.

Comment: this is perhaps the most complex part of any relational DB, if you google "sql server optimizer heuristics" you will get plenty of material, such as [this](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/t-sql-programming/how-to-confuse-the-sql-server-query-optimizer/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are entire *books* on the topic, so you're not going to get a quick and comprehensive answer here.

The basic approach is to apply a set of rules, with scoring criteria associated with each.    The approach with the lowest total resource score will prevail.

Common rules, include:

1. Process tables in a complex joined query from the most selective to the least.  This approach minimizes the overall I/O used by the query in its entirety by progressively lessening the number of potentially qualifying rows that have to be evaluated.
2. Where an index is available (for a join, or a WHERE restriction) try to use it consistent with Rule #1.   For large joins, clustered indexes usually offer an advantage.  Sometimes, the index is all that is needed to satisfy the query need, and the table itself does not have to be read at all.
3. Enterprise databases often maintain "statistics" about the number of rows, and the relative selectivity of data values found for a particular column or index.   If values are diverse (i.e. there are few rows that meet your JOIN/WHERE criteria) it will be preferentially:  its resource score will be lower.
4. Opportunities for parallel execution will be evaluated, and used if available.   So if there are independent chunks of the query, the optimizer will probably try to run them in parallel.
5. Smaller tables can be scanned faster and with less I/O then larger tables.   These tables will be be preferentially bumped up in execution order where possible.  (This applies, as well, to subqueries that have been statistically predicted to return few rows).

This is an enormously complex topic, and the things I have suggested above are just the most common strategies used.   Query optimizers are deep and complicated programs, and provide much of the proprietary advantage offered by different databases.  Microsoft has an *excellent* series of books on the SQL Server Internals.   If you want to dive deep into the topic, I highly recommend these.

You asked for an article:  since the basic strategies are the same, this  article from Oracle would pretty much apply for other enterprise DBs like SQL Server or DB2:

[Query Optimizer Concepts](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/TGSQL/tgsql_optcncpt.htm#TGSQL227)